# Why does the set of submodules of a module that are direct sums of irreducible submodules have a maximal element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, semi-simple-rings

I was reading the proof that every R-module M of an artinian semisimple ring R is the direct sum of all irreducible R-submodules M. In the proof they stated that the set
$$\mathcal{F}:=\{N\subset M: N \text{ is the direct sum of its irreducible submodules}\}$$
has a maximal element. I was trying to see why such a maximal element exists.

My attempt: Let $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}\subset \mathcal{F}$ be a total ordered subset of $\mathcal{F}$ ($I$ is any indexation set). I want to prove that $N=\cup_{i\in I} N_i$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. We know that for each $i\in I$ there's an indexation set $J_i$ such that $N_i=\bigoplus_{k_i\in J_i} M_{k_i}$ with $M_{k_i}$ irreducible submodules of $N_i$. Define $$\Lambda :=\cup_{i\in I}\{k_i\in J_i:M_{k_i}=M_{k_{io}} \text{ for some }i_o\in I\setminus\{i\} \text{ and } k_{i_o}\in J_{i_o}\}$$

Obviously $\sum_{k_i\in (\cup_{i\in I} J_i)\setminus \Lambda} M_{k_i}$ is direct sum, but I got stuck for adding ***only one time*** such irreducible submodules $M_{i_k}$ associated to $\Lambda$ to asure the direct sum.

Comment: You should be careful with your phrasing--it sounds like you really mean to say $M$ is the direct sum of *some* collection of irreducible submodules (and similarly for $N$ in the definition of $\mathcal{F}$).  That's very different from being the direct sum of *all* of its irreducible submodules.

Comment: You're right, but every irreducible modules of $N$ must be an irreducible of some $N_i$. This is easy to check.

Comment: In any case, it sounds like the proof you are reading may just be wrong (or missing enough details that it is seriously incomplete).  What source are you reading from?  The usual proof would not use that poset $\mathcal{F}$ but would instead use a different one, or else would not use Zorn's lemma at all but would instead use transfinite recursion.

Comment: I'm reading my notes of class. But here https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter9.pdf they use the same: proof of theorem 9.1.2. (a) implies (b). The part that they asure that the maximal exists is what I need to see with more details

Comment: By the way, it is not true that $\sum_{k_i\in (\cup_{i\in I} J_i)\setminus \Lambda} M_{k_i}$ is a direct sum and I'm not sure why you think that is "obvious".

Comment: The proof of (a) implies (b) in Theorem 9.1.2 is doing something quite different.  There the poset consists of subsets of $I$ (some set of simple modules whose sum is $M$), *not* of submodules of $M$.

Comment: Sorry, I add that $\{N_i\}$ is a total ordered subset of $\mathcal{F}$. It must be  direct sum because if not, the index will be in $\Lambda$

Comment: I know, it's different but I think that the main idea is same

Comment: Consider $R=\mathbb{R}$, $M=\mathbb{R}^2$, $N_0=\{(t,t):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $N_1=M$.  Then $N_0$ itself is a simple module, and $N_1$ can be written as the direct sum of two simple modules $A=\{(t,0):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $B=\{(0,t):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.  All three of these simple modules are different, but the sum $N_0+A+B$ is not direct.

Comment: $\{N_0,A,B\}$  is not  total ordered with the inclusion order.

Comment: The chain here is just $\{N_0,N_1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the proof you are reading is incorrect.  There is no straightforward way to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under unions of chains; knowing that each $N_i$ is a direct sum of simple submodules is not particularly helpful for proving that $\bigcup N_i$ is a direct sum of simple submodules.

For a correct proof, you want to use a different poset which forces the direct sum decompositions in such a chain to be "compatible".  Here's one way to formulate it.  Instead of using your poset $\mathcal{F}$, use the poset $$\mathcal{G}=
\left\{(N,S):N\subseteq M\text{ is a submodule, $S$ is a set of simple submodules of $N$, and }N=\bigoplus_{A\in S}A\right\}$$ ordered by saying $(N,S)\leq (N',S')$ if $N\subseteq N'$ and $S\subseteq S'$.

Now suppose you have a chain $\{(N_i,S_i):i\in I\}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$; I claim that $(N,S)\in \mathcal{G}$ where $N=\bigcup N_i$ (or $N=\{0\}$ if the chain is empty) and $S=\bigcup S_i$, and so $(N,S)$ is an upper bound for the chain.  It is clear that $N$ is a submodule of $M$, $S$ is a set of simple submodules of $N$, and $N$ is the sum of the elements of $S$.  It remains to show that this sum is direct.  If the sum were not direct, this would mean there are finitely many elements $A_1,\dots,A_n\in S$ and elements $a_j,b_j\in A_j$ such that $\sum a_j=\sum b_j$ but $a_j\neq b_j$ for some $j$.  But there is some $i\in I$ such that $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are all in $S_i$, and so this would contradict the fact that $N_i$ is the direct sum of the elements of $S_i$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the set $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under the union of any chain. Let $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}\subset \mathcal{F}$ a total ordered subset of $\mathcal{F}$. Clearly $M=\cup_i N_i$ is a sum of irreducible $R$-modules. Write $M=\sum_{j\in J} T_j$ with $T_j$ irreducible modules. Let $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{P}(J)$  such that for all $S_o\in \mathcal{S}$, $\sum_{s\in S_o}T_s=\bigoplus_{s\in S_o}T_s$. $S$ is not empty because for each $j\in J$, $\{j\}\in \mathcal{S}$. Let's see that $\mathcal{S}$ has a maximal. Let $\{S_r\}$ be a total ordered subset of $\mathcal{S}$ and let $\hat{S}=\cup_r S_r$. Pick any $s_o\in\hat{S}$ and  $x\in T_{s_o}\cap\sum_{s\in\hat{S}\setminus\{s_o\}} T_s$. Then $x=x_{s_1}+\cdots+x_{s_{n}}$ with $x_{s_l}\in T_{s_l}$. Since $\{S_r\}$ is a chain, there's $n_o\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $x_{s_l}\in T_{s_{n_o}}$ for all $l\in\{1,..,n\}$. Then $x\in T_{s_o}\cap T_{s_{n_o}}$. Since each $T$ is irreducible, $x=0$. Conclution $\mathcal{S}$ has a maximal, call it $S_o$.

Finally, let's prove that $M=\bigoplus_{s\in S_o} T_s$. Clearly $\bigoplus_{s\in S_o} T_s\subset M$. Suppose that there's $x\in M\setminus\bigoplus_{s\in S_o} T_s$ with $x\neq 0$. Then, $x\in T_p$ for some $p\in J$ with $p\notin S_o$. It's easy to check that $\sum_{s\in S_o\cup\{p\}}T_s=\bigoplus_{s\in S_o\cup\{p\}}T_s$. This contradicts the maximality of $S_o$. Hence $M$ is a direct sum of irreducible modules, i.e., it's the direct sum of **all** its irreducible submodules.